# Doesn't want to add controls on a specific page

Tags: vba, excel

I'm running into an unusual problem.
I have a set of procedures to add a bunch of controls on different pages
One to add the frames

```
Public Sub AddFramesNP(form, pagina, nrpag)
Set cControl = form!main.Pages(nrpag).Controls.Add("Forms.Frame.1", "io" & masina, True)
        With cControl
            .Caption = "IO"
            .Width = 210
            .Height = 360
            .Top = 2
            .Left = 5
        End With
    Set cControl = form!main.Pages(nrpag).Controls.Add("Forms.Frame.1", "nio" & masina, True)
        With cControl
            .Caption = "nIO"
            .Width = 210
            .Height = 360
            .Top = 2
            .Left = 220
        End With
    Set cControl = form!main.Pages(nrpag).Controls.Add("Forms.Frame.1", "desc" & masina, True)
        With cControl
            .Caption = "Descriere"
            .Width = 210
            .Height = 360
            .Top = 2
            .Left = 435
        End With
End Sub
```

One to add the Labels

```
Public Sub AddLabsNP(form, pagina, replicare, den, den1, den2)
Dim k, l As Integer
    If den = 1 Then
        Set cControl = form.Controls("io" & masina).Add("Forms.Label.1", "lden1" & pagina, True)
            With cControl
                .Caption = den1
                .Width = 40
                .Height = 10
                .Top = 5
                .Left = 5
            End With
        Set cControl = form.Controls("nio" & masina).Add("Forms.Label.1", "lden1nio" & pagina, True)
            With cControl
                .Caption = den1
                .Width = 40
                .Height = 10
                .Top = 5
                .Left = 5
            End With
        End If
   If replicare = 1 Then
        Set cControl = form.Controls("io" & masina).Add("Forms.Label.1", "lden2" & pagina, True)
        With cControl
            .Caption = den2
            .Width = 40
            .Height = 10
            .Top = 165
            .Left = 5
        End With
    Set cControl = form.Controls("nio" & masina).Add("Forms.Label.1", "lden2nio" & pagina, True)
        With cControl
            .Caption = den2
            .Width = 40
            .Height = 10
            .Top = 165
            .Left = 5
        End With
    End If
    Do While l < replicare + 1
        Set cControl = form.Controls("io" & masina).Add("Forms.Label.1", "lreper" & l & pagina, True)
            With cControl
                .Caption = "Reper"
                .Width = 35
                .Height = 9
                .Top = 25 + k
                .Left = 5
            End With
        Set cControl = form.Controls("io" & masina).Add("Forms.Label.1", "lsn" & l & pagina, True)
            With cControl
                .Caption = "SN"
                .Width = 35
                .Height = 9
                .Top = 25 + k
                .Left = 70
            End With
        Set cControl = form.Controls("io" & masina).Add("Forms.Label.1", "lqt" & l & pagina, True)
            With cControl
                .Caption = "Qt"
                .Width = 35
                .Height = 9
                .Top = 25 + k
                .Left = 155
            End With
        Set cControl = form.Controls("nio" & masina).Add("Forms.Label.1", "lrepernio" & l & pagina, True)
            With cControl
                .Caption = "Reper"
                .Width = 35
                .Height = 9
                .Top = 25 + k
                .Left = 5
            End With
        Set cControl = form.Controls("nio" & masina).Add("Forms.Label.1", "lsnnio" & l & pagina, True)
            With cControl
                .Caption = "SN"
                .Width = 35
                .Height = 9
                .Top = 25 + k
                .Left = 70
            End With
        Set cControl = form.Controls("nio" & masina).Add("Forms.Label.1", "lqtnio" & l & pagina, True)
            With cControl
                .Caption = "Qt"
                .Width = 35
                .Height = 9
                .Top = 25 + k
                .Left = 155
            End With
            k = k + 155
            l = l + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

And one to add the ComboBoxes

```
Public Sub AddCboxsNP(form, pagina, replicare, nrcboxs)
Dim k, l As Integer
l = 1
        Do While l < nrcboxs + 1
            Set cControl = form.Controls("io" & masina).Add("Forms.ComboBox.1", "combo" & l & pagina, True)
                With cControl
                    .Width = 60
                    .Height = 14
                    .Top = 40 + k
                    .Left = 5
                End With
            Set cControl = form.Controls("io" & masina).Add("Forms.TextBox.1", "sn" & l & pagina, True)
                With cControl
                    .Width = 80
                    .Height = 28
                    .Top = 40 + k
                    .Left = 70
                End With
            Set cControl = form.Controls("io" & masina).Add("Forms.TextBox.1", "q" & l & pagina, True)
                With cControl
                    .Width = 30
                    .Height = 14
                    .Top = 40 + k
                    .Left = 155
                End With
            Set cControl = form.Controls("nio" & masina).Add("Forms.ComboBox.1", "combo" & l & "nio" & pagina, True)
                With cControl
                    .Width = 60
                    .Height = 14
                    .Top = 40 + k
                    .Left = 5
                End With
            Set cControl = form.Controls("nio" & masina).Add("Forms.TextBox.1", "sn" & l & "nio" & pagina, True)
                With cControl
                    .Width = 80
                    .Height = 28
                    .Top = 40 + k
                    .Left = 70
                End With
            Set cControl = form.Controls("nio" & masina).Add("Forms.TextBox.1", "q" & l & "nio" & pagina, True)
                With cControl
                    .Width = 30
                    .Height = 14
                    .Top = 40 + k
                    .Left = 155
                End With
        If replicare = 2 Then
            Set cControl = form.Controls("io" & masina).Add("Forms.ComboBox.1", "combo" & l & "2" & pagina, True)
                With cControl
                    .Width = 60
                    .Height = 14
                    .Top = 200 + k
                    .Left = 5
                End With
            Set cControl = form.Controls("io" & masina).Add("Forms.TextBox.1", "sn" & l & "2" & pagina, True)
                With cControl
                    .Width = 80
                    .Height = 28
                    .Top = 200 + k
                    .Left = 70
                End With
            Set cControl = form.Controls("io" & masina).Add("Forms.TextBox.1", "q" & l & "2" & pagina, True)
                With cControl
                    .Width = 30
                    .Height = 14
                    .Top = 200 + k
                    .Left = 155
                End With
            Set cControl = form.Controls("nio" & masina).Add("Forms.ComboBox.1", "combo" & l & "2nio" & pagina, True)
                With cControl
                    .Width = 60
                    .Height = 14
                    .Top = 200 + k
                    .Left = 5
                End With
            Set cControl = form.Controls("nio" & masina).Add("Forms.TextBox.1", "sn" & l & "2nio" & pagina, True)
                With cControl
                    .Width = 80
                    .Height = 28
                    .Top = 200 + k
                    .Left = 70
                End With
            Set cControl = form.Controls("nio" & masina).Add("Forms.TextBox.1", "q" & l & "2nio" & pagina, True)
                With cControl
                    .Width = 30
                    .Height = 14
                    .Top = 200 + k
                    .Left = 155
                End With
            End If
            k = k + 35
            l = l + 1
        Loop
End Sub
```

The problem is that when I want to use them I don't know why but they don't work for page 3 (I use them for page 2 and they work fine). I have to use this ones just for these 2 pages (2 and 3). And I have another set of procedures for the pages that contain multipages that work fine for 3 pages.
I really don't see where's the problem. I tried to add components manually (through code) and it worked fine. Did I do something that makes this procedures to work just 1 time? I don't see what because are the same with other procedures that work multiple times!
Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Are you saying that it doesn't work for `nrpag = 3`? What error are you getting? Have you tried running in debug mode?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work for page 3... I don't know why... I don't get any error... it adds the frames but not the ComboBoxes or the labels. For page 2 it works just fine.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code in debug mode? What happens then?

Answer (score 0):

I know it is an old thread but just the same... :)

I am taking the Frames Code as an example. Please use it as a sample for the rest :)

Also this example creates the frames in a MultiPage1.

Let me know if this helps :)

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    AddFramesNP Me, 3, 2
End Sub

Public Sub AddFramesNP(form As UserForm, masina, nrpag)
    Dim cControl As Object

    With form
        Set cControl = .MultiPage1.Pages(nrpag).Controls.Add("Forms.Frame.1", "io" & masina)
        With cControl
            .Caption = "IO"
            .Width = 210: .Height = 360: .Top = 2
            .Left = 5
        End With

        Set cControl = .MultiPage1.Pages(nrpag).Controls.Add("Forms.Frame.1", "nio" & masina)
        With cControl
            .Caption = "nIO"
            .Width = 210: .Height = 360: .Top = 2
            .Left = 220
        End With

        Set cControl = .MultiPage1.Pages(nrpag).Controls.Add("Forms.Frame.1", "desc" & masina)
        With cControl
            .Caption = "Descriere"
            .Width = 210: .Height = 360: .Top = 2
            .Left = 435
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```